# Could not initialize class org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.MatVector

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencv, javacv, bytedeco-javacv

I have a problem with the following class org.bytedeco.opencv.opencv_core.MatVector. These are the related dependencies that I added to my POM:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.openpnp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0-0</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>openblas</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.5-1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>openblas-platform</artifactId>
        <version>0.3.5-1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacv</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9</version> 
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencv</artifactId>
        <version>4.7.0-1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco</groupId>
        <artifactId>javacpp</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets</groupId>
        <artifactId>ffmpeg-platform</artifactId>
        <version>4.1-1.4.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please add javacv-platform as shown in the README.md file: https://github.com/bytedeco/javacv/